# Multiple dependencies with hibernate.cfg.xml at root in shaded jar

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-shade-plugin

I am trying to shade a jar with multiple dependencies implementing hibernate entities. A number of the dependencies have the hibernate.cfg.xml at the root of the jar so only an indeterminate hibernate.cfg.xml is added to the final jar. Playing around with the appending transformer but have had no luck so far.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
    <resource>**/hibernate.cfg.xml</resource>
</transformer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I kinda gave up - just too many dependencies to deal with, defeated :( I went with a standard jar and library dir.

```
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-libs</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
                                <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/bin</outputDirectory>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <useUniqueVersions>false</useUniqueVersions>
                                <mainClass>com.loader.App</mainClass>
                                <classpathPrefix>../libs/</classpathPrefix>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```